# AWS Console - How much I'll pay after?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm wondering if there is a way to see how much I'll potentially pay for all my active AWS services after the free trial has expired based on current activity?

Answer (score 2):

The [AWS Cost Explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/) has many features that I think you will find useful for answering this question. It can forecast expected spend, and you might be able to filter projected free tier spend.

Answer (score 1):

Cost explorer is a best way to find how much you would pay. And also you can set up alerts in AWS to make sure you dont go beyond a certain limit. That way, you know your budget is fixed and set up alerts to stop services based on how much you can spend.